# Efficiently Predict the Output of a Number Processing Algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, sequence, prediction

I am working on a bit of code that needs to be able to efficiently predict (preferably in O(1) time) the output of the following algorithm when presented with two ints m and n.

```
algorithm(m,n):
history = set()
while True:
    if (m,n) in history:
        return False
    elif n == m:
        return True
    else:
        history.add((m,n))
        if m>n:
            x = m-n
            y = 2*n
            m = x
            n = y
        else:
            x = 2*m
            y = n-m
            m = x
            n = y
```

Note that when (m,n) appears in the following algorithm's history, you've entered an infinite loop (i.e. 2,1 -> 1,2 -> 2,1...); when m==n the algorithm can proceed only one step further and must terminate (i.e. 5,5 -> 10,0 -> 10,0...). Essentially I need to be able to predict if m(current) and n(current) will ever match.

PS, if this algorithm has a name I'd love to know it. Furthermore, if there exists good reading on this topic (predicting numerical sequences, etc...) I'd love to be directed to it.

Comment: Smells like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: @Psi: This is way easier than the halting problem. We only need to analyze the behavior of one non-Turing-complete algorithm. It's even guaranteed to halt.

Comment: Not if you enter an infinite loop, as stated. I still don't see how that could happen

Comment: @Psi: The algorithm detects when it would enter an infinite loop, using the `history` set, and terminates. As for an input that would produce an infinite loop without `history`, consider `algorithm(1, 2)`.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood that sentence

Comment: Are you looking for the mathematical solution? One naive option is to hold a precalculated map of values per inputs. of course that this solution is very limited.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming positive integer input, this algorithm will return True if and only if (m+n)/gcd(m, n) is a power of two.

Proof sketch:

Divide both m and n by gcd(m, n) at the start of the algorithm; this will not change the return value.

If the sum of m and n is divisible by an odd prime p after doing this, then both m and n need to become divisible by p for the algorithm to return True, but neither m nor n can do so.

If the sum of m and n is a power of two, then both m and n will become divisible by another factor of 2 on each iteration until both are equal.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let's reduce the update step to a single line.  On each iteration, **m** updates to the absolute difference; **n** updates to twice the smaller number.

```
else:
    history.add((m,n))
    m, n = abs(m-n), 2 * min(m, n)
```

This highlights the non-linearity of the iteration.  Each update breaks into the two classes you first programmed; the recurrence breaks into multiple classes on each further iteration.

I believe that the short answer for this is *no* -- you cannot predict the outcome in a time reasonably shorter than simply executing the algorithm.

The division point for switching large vs smaller is when one number is 3 times the other.  In that space, the algorithm closes the gap simply: subtract the smaller form the larger, then double the smaller.  Once they get within the 3x range, the system quickly turns chaotic: you cannot state that two nearby pairs will have results that remain nearby as the algorithm progresses, not for any adjacent pairs.